# Automate static and DHCP switch

Tags: windows-7, windows, dhcp, static-ip

Is it possible to automate switching the DHCP and Static IP usage for a specified interface in Win7?

I have an  AP connected to an other and when the other AP goes offline it does not give my PC an  IP address because DHCP is on the other AP. I get 169.254.x.x address and can't reach my AP or the NAS connected to my AP. Any solution would be good except manually switching the interface's setting between DHCP and static.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be to *always* use a static IP address that's outside your first AP's DHCP range. From the sounds of it, there's no reason your computer needs to actually switch IP addresses (unless you've left something out.)

Other than that, you could write yourself a couple simple batch scripts to switch the settings.

For static IP:

> netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1

<sub>(more info at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257748)</sub>

And for DHCP:

> netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp

Copy those lines in to Notepad, Save As using .bat as the extension, drop them on your desktop, and run as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Simply right click on the network interface and then click Properties.  Double click TCP/IP V4

Click the Alternate Configuration tab.  Click User Configured radio button. Enter your desired static info here.  Click OK

Now that interface will try DHCP and then use your user configured settings if DHCP fails or is not available